# Qt webkit as an overlay on top of opengl

Tags: qt, opengl, webkit

I'm writing a game engine and using opengl/qt. I'm trying to use webkit as a 2D UI overlay for menus etc. I found some examples but none of them work for some reason. For example adding two widgets QGLWidget and a QWebView doesn't seem to work.
How should I do this without losing much performance?

Comment: Which examples were you looking at?  I'm curious about this stuff, too.  AFAIK, for overlays to work, you need to use a graphics scene so Qt can blend the widgets when painting.  Basically, GLWidget's GL Context needs to be shared somehow.  If it turns out that QWebView is the problem, you might look at QML for the UI, which I hear is just as easy as HTML/CSS

Comment: I was using a QGLWidget and a QWebView widget which I added together with QGraphicsScene. This example uses the classes in a different manner and here it is working http://zester.googlecode.com/files/qt-labs-modelviewer.zip. However I also found QGraphicsWebView which also seems like a good alternative. If I find something I let you know. BTW I know about QML and maybe that also works, but I decided to use webkit as it is exactly a webbrowser.

Comment: @Bjorn QML should not be the alternative to the HTML page, but CrazyIvanovich said that it is as easy as HTML. You can easily [embed WebKit in QML](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmlwebkit.html)

Comment: @leemes Nice that it is so easy to embed webkit in QML. Is it also easy to have a OpenGL widget with webkit on top of it in QML? Because then I might as well use QML.

Comment: I've never done that in Qt4 with basic QML stuff (but in Qt5 with Qt3D), but the things you should read up are: [Loading QGraphicsWidget objects in QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-integration.html#loading-qgraphicswidget-objects-in-qml) and [QGraphicsProxyWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsproxywidget.html). I think you can create a proxy for your existing widget and put this into your QML scene. (Note that a QML file is viewed as a QGraphicsScene, at least in Qt4.)

Comment: But as it is possible to embed WebKit into QML, you should rethink if you really want to write the UI in HTML if you have QML, which is more powerful and easier to write in my opinion.

Comment: Please also note that writing a QDeclarativeItem (which implements a QML item in C++) would be more lightweight than implementing a widget and exposing this to QML via a QGraphicsProxyItem. It will also be portable to Qt5 as Qt5 will not use a graphics scene anymore. (Not even widgets per default.) Within the QDeclarativeItem, you implement a paint method and can call OpenGL commands from within this paint method. It's basically the same than how you would implement painting in a QGLWidget subclass.